# opencv.hpp not found in NDK build on Windows

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I am getting some issues here while I am trying to compile my code with Cgywin.

```
$ /cygdrive/c/native_work/android-ndk-r8b/ndk-build
Android NDK: WARNING: Unsupported source file extensions in jni/Android.mk for module main
Android NDK:   NotePaperDetector.hpp
Install        : libmain.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libmain.so
```

so how I can compile the .hpp file ?

Now as @mah you said I have removed it from my Android.mk but now its showing some different error -

```
$ /cygdrive/c/native_work/android-ndk-r8b/ndk-build
Compile++ thumb  : main <= NotePaperDetector.cpp
In file included from jni/NotePaperDetector.hpp:4:0,
             from jni/NotePaperDetector.cpp:1:
jni/NoteLocation.hpp:4:30: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
/cygdrive/c/native_work/android-ndk-r8b/build/core/build-binary.mk:255: recipe for      target `obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/main/NotePaperDetector.o' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/main/NotePaperDetector.o] Error 1
```

Comment: If this is a header file, it should be #include'd by something else that get compiled; it should not be compiled directly.

Comment: @mah Its already included in my .cpp file , but now I have removed it from my Android.mk file ..but still showing some errors.

Comment: I would have to expect that the errors under this change are not the same as the errors you received while referencing the header in your mk file. I can't guess what those errors are though, so you'll need to expand on your comment -- or perhaps edit your question instead.

Comment: How do you reference OpenCV from your Android.mk?

Comment: @Alex using Application.mk   - 
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a

Comment: [@anonymous](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1037312/anonymous) I see no mention of OpenCV in your Application.mk _not that there should be, normally you find it in Android.mk_

Answer (score 0):

With the latest NDK releases you don't need Cygwin at all.

By the way a GNU/Linux platform is always the best for Android developers.

Comment: How is it an answer? Did you see that the question had been edited, and has nothing to do now with the **SUBJ**. _Yes, it's probably worth editing_

Comment: @AlexCohn if the roots of the problem are simply wrong probably it's worth trying to explain why he is not supposed to work this way. How i can take this question into account if the question itself is wrong ?